# Resumé builder app

Tags: javascript, beginner, angular.js, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Wrote this an hour or so after learning some basics.

Took me a while because I had to write it in a way to fit the previous structure of my page. Basically, there are three rows of data. There *has* to be three `row` classes in bootstrap because otherwise the columns would basically stack on top of each other and I did not like that because they were different heights (kind of like Pinterest). I also didn't like the idea of having to set a fixed height to the columns, so I had to write the Angular in a way that I could basically insert data into each row separately as opposed to doing an `ng-repeat` on one column in just one row for the entire thing.

How do you guys think I did? Could anything be improved, or is this OK for a first go at it? What should I keep in mind moving forward for code cleanliness or maintainability? How are my naming conventions?

Note:

- Cleaned out the text from `app.js` just to make it easier to look through.
- Cleaned out a lot of the HTML, used only what was necessary for this example.
- Used `ngSanitize` module to be able to have my HTML tags in the `app.js` be outputted as HTML and not just plain text.

Also, I'm using `@{{ }}` instead of `{{ }}` because this is on a Laravel project, and Laravel also shares the `{{ }}` blade syntax so I can basically ignore blade by prepending an "@" and it will be used for Angular.

---

**app.js:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('resume', ['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller('ResumeController', function() {
        this.content = accolades;
    });

    var accolades = {
        rowOne: [
            {
                title: '',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '' },
                    { li: '' },
                    { li: '' },
                    { li: '' },
                    { li: '' }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: '',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' },
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' },
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' }
                ]
            }
        ],
        rowTwo: [
            {
                title: '',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: '',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' }
                ]
            }
        ],
        rowThree: [
            {
                title: 'Startups',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '<a href=""></a>' }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: '',
                descriptions: [
                    { li: '<b></b>.' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
})();
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
<div ng-controller="ResumeController as resume">

    <div class="pullUp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="row in resume.content.rowOne">
                <h4>@{{ row.title }}</h4>

                <ul class="resume-ul">
                    <li ng-repeat="description in row.descriptions">
                        <null ng-bind-html="description.li"></null>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pullUp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="row in resume.content.rowTwo">
                <h4>@{{ row.title }}</h4>

                <ul class="resume-ul">
                    <li ng-repeat="description in row.descriptions">
                        <null ng-bind-html="description.li"></null>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pullUp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat=
            "row in resume.content.rowThree">
                <h4>@{{ row.title }}</h4>

                <ul class="resume-ul">
                    <li ng-repeat="description in row.descriptions">
                        <null ng-bind-html="description.li"></null>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: One thing I want to mention now before I review (if I do): your description links are not going to work; `ng-bind-html` will strip out the `a` tags due to passing it through `$sanitize` because you do not explicitly mark the html fragment as trusted. Please see [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to provide your accolades as a service such as a constant rather than a var. Also, you can chain the definitions of module, controller, and services together with dot notation. Good work considering your short time learning some basics.